# Encoding string column to numeric values by predefined rule

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have following DataFrame:

```
   voting_result project   scene
    Bad          ccus      345943
    Good         ccus      311129
    Bad          ccus      309082
    Bad          ccus      331613
    Good         ccus      331615 
    Not Sure     ccus      331616
```

What is `Pandas`  way to `encode` voting_result column to integers by following rule `{'Bad':0, 'Good':1, 'Not Sure':2`} and to get following resut

```
voting_result    project    scene
        0         ccus      345943
        1         ccus      311129
        0         ccus      309082
        0         ccus      331613
        1         ccus      331615 
        2         ccus      331616
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dictionary`:

```
d = {'Bad':0, 'Good':1, 'Not Sure':2}
df['voting_result'] = df['voting_result'].map(d)
print (df)
   voting_result project   scene
0              0    ccus  345943
1              1    ccus  311129
2              0    ccus  309082
3              0    ccus  331613
4              1    ccus  331615
5              2    ccus  331616
```